# I want to Create A desktop Application with Adobe Air PHP MYSQL

Tags: air, adobe

I want to first of all thank everyone for the help I got here in the past. After completing my web application using Html, PHP, jQuery,  Javascript, CSS, MYSQL,  I realized I don’t want a website. In the end, for security, I prefer knowing who will be accessing my application. Having said that, I want to use most of the work I already did for my website. I understand I can use PHP with AIR and MySQL.  I read that many would recommend using SQLite, but my problem is that I will constantly be updating the database. I also read there are some security issues using MYSQL and AIR.

Question 1,  if I took the "necessary" security precautions within PHP which connects to MYSQL, would that be ok or is there soething else I should be aware of wit AIR ?

Question 2  if I really need to use SQLite, is there a way to connect to Mysql so that I may update the database.

I'm open to suggestions if there is a third party software that will covert my project to a desktop application with connectivity to MYSQL I also have a third party flash embedded.

Thanks

Comment: SQLite is *local* database. It doesn't compete with MySQL. You might need it if you need complex local queries, not because it's "better" than MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Make it mandatory to sign in to the website to use it. Will that not be sufficient to know who is accessing your application?

PHP is a server side language. Adobe AIR is desktop application framework. I am not sure that converting a PHP-MySQL application to an Adobe AIR application will be a trivial task.

You can take the distributed application route though by doing the client side in AIR and writing the web services in PHP/MySQL. And if you want a distributed database too, it will get lot more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

You can build a rest api with php and integrate it with adobe air applications via http no need js for this. Just use actionscript with urlloader urlstream.
If you need an offline db you can use sqlite and sync with Mysql via php.

Answer (score -1):

You'll have to forget PHP and use javascript and SQL sintax to do it. You can check this pretty guide from adobe to do so http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/html/dev/air_htmldevguide.pdf
It won't be easy ;P